# How to create alert and event service using BAC0 in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

can someone help me in creating a alert and event service for a bacnet code written using python BAC0 library.

Comment: Could you show us what attempts you have made?

Comment: I have tried with creating a device. i am able to read its property data and able to implement cov for that device. but i didnt have any idea how to implement a alert type of senario where device send some warning if its value exceed a range. Is their any module in BAC0 library which need to be used in these senarios like for COV we have one.

Answer (score 0):

Event and alert are not supported yet.
PR are welcomed though !